# Wordpress equivalent to Drupal Views?

Tags: customization, conditional-content

**Is there a Wordpress plugin that provides a subset of the functionality found in Drupal Views?**

Specifically, I'm looking for the ability to use a Views-like plugin to pull in fields of content based on criteria like date, title, etc. and place them in a block-like area on particular pages.

I'm aware of this question thread ([How to replicate some of Drupal Views functionality in WordPress?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/how-to-replicate-some-of-drupal-views-functionality-in-wordpress)), but it is from over 4 years ago, so I'm wondering if there are any new solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not identical to Drupal Views, but i think [WP Views](http://wp-types.com/home/views-create-elegant-displays-for-your-content/) is the closest you will get to Drupal Views.

I am a Drupal guy, and i use WP Views for every Wordpress project i create.